# How to say "when their ears stopped ringing"?

Tags: translation

The best I could come up with was 等他们的耳朵不响了, which just seems wrong and inadequate. I was wondering whether there was a specific term for it.

Comment: searching **ichacha**  with "ears ringing":
    i have a ringing in my ears    我耳朵嗡嗡作响,a drumming in the ears    耳鸣, ( **iciba** :...耳朵里(久久)地回响着),once Chinese text is available, for further usage examples search **bkrs** :耳朵嗡嗡作响:耳朵嗡嗡响|耳朵嗡鸣,耳鸣:many more examples:tinnitus; ringing in the ears; syrigmus; singing:
神经性耳鸣 nervous tinnitus
我耳鸣。 My ears are tingling (humming; ringing; singing). **etc.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ears ringing" translated into Chinese is "耳嗚"

> https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%80%B3%E9%B8%A3
>
> *係指外在環境沒發出聲音卻聽見聲音的一種狀況* (hearing sound when there is no external source of such sound)
>
> *最常見的原因是因噪音型聽力損失* (most common cause of this impairment of  hearing ability is loud noise )

“when their ears stopped ringing” could be translated as "**等他们的耳嗚停止时**"

But "耳嗚" is quite a formal (medical) and literary term. The more colloquial term for "ear ringing" is "耳中嗡嗡作响" therefore,   your sentence could be translated as "**等他们耳中的嗡嗡响声停下來时**" (when the buzzing sound in their ears stopped)